# $scope inside and outside ng-include behave differently

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I did some experiment to create a ng-change behaviour on 2 different selectbox while carying the same $scope. one is inside ng-include directive, meanwhile the other one is outside the ng-include directive, the interesting part is though when I implement data-binding it turns out okay, but when I tried to look at my console tab it return differently

the one outside the ng-include directive was okay whereas the one inside the ng-include directive always returns value 'a' or static value

this is the **index.html** mockup

```
  <select ng-model="list" ng-change="changeOutsideTemplate()">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
  </select>

  {{list}}

  <div ng-include="test"></div> //this scope caries test.html
```

this is the **test.html** mockup

```
<select ng-model="list" ng-change="changeInsideTemplate()">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>

{{list}}
```

this is the controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.test = "test.html";
  $scope.list = "a";

  $scope.changeInsideTemplate = function() {
    console.log($scope.list); //always returns 'a'
  }

  $scope.changeOutsideTemplate = function() {
    console.log($scope.list); //this is the correct way
  }

});
```

this is the working [**example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KjHSgyeLQ2CYgnsFrO3J)

why do you think the cause of this issue ? anyone care to elaborate ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ng-include` directive create a new child scope.
here is the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

when your model in `ng-include` html  as `<select ng-model="list" ng-change="changeInsideTemplate()">` then angular will check for a model `list` in its child scope, then angular will realize there is no `model` called `list` in `ng-include` child scope. then angular will create a new child scope model called `list` inside of child scope.

if u do like

```
<select ng-model="$parent.list" ng-change="changeInsideTemplate()">
```

then angular will check model `list` in parent scope. in the parent scope of `ng-include` scope contains `$scope.list` which we are concern.

here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QRejSBTiRrxAH4Z4se3c?p=preview)

---

OR you can use like below as @dfsq suggested in the comment.

> controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.test = "test.html";
  $scope.list = {value: 'a'};

  $scope.changeInsideTemplate = function() {
    console.log($scope.list.value); //always returns 'a'
  }

  $scope.changeOutsideTemplate = function() {
    console.log($scope.list.value); //this is the correct way
  }
});
```

> index.html

```
<select ng-model="list.value" ng-change="changeOutsideTemplate()">
```

> test.html

```
<select ng-model="list.value" ng-change="changeInsideTemplate()">
```

in `test.html` angular will check for `list.value` then angular will know `value` is a property of a object and there is no object called `list` with in the child scope. then angular will search the object(`list`) in parent scope like it will search entire hierarchy.

here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NRvNlTiXH10KOgKtqqUl?p=preview)

---

if you have `ng-include` inside `ng-include` then second `ng-include` create a child scope on first `ng-include`

then in `test.html`

```
<div ng-include="$parent.include"></div> // because `$scope.include` in parent scope
```

and in `include.html`

```
<select ng-model="$parent.$parent.list" ng-change="otherChanging()"> // because `$scope.list` is in parent scope of parent scope (second upper parent scope).
```

here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ePuRNHnbPW3qfLlNYCqT?p=preview) using $parent.

here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rqt8Gba9G36snV82gnR0?p=preview) using Object.

using object more suitable.

Comment: It's correct. Or better fix is to use `$scope.list = {value: 'a'}` better and `ng-model="list.value"`.

Comment: god now that you mention it I could see the directive info on the documentation.. wow interesting, so that's why it didn't work like it's supposed to work.. thanks for your explanation, I understand now!

Comment: btw what if the case is like this ? http://plnkr.co/edit/KjHSgyeLQ2CYgnsFrO3J?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ePuRNHnbPW3qfLlNYCqT?p=preview here is the solution. second method will more suitable use it. this example is using `$parent`;

Comment: so basically every ng-include added, new child scope is added also.. but the method is more suitable if using list.value compared the one using $parent.$parent.list I think... I understand now.. thank you guys! it was fun having this discussion with you guys..